# can't access web3 object in Drizzle Box

Tags: truffle, drizzle

I am building a DAPP based on drizzle box. I am struggling to find out how can i get the web3 instance without initiating a new one
I want to end up with something like :

```
this.props.web3.eth
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described here : https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle-react/issues/22

This can be done via:

```
this.context.drizzle.web3...
```

In order to make this work, you have to pass the context variable to the constructor:

```
constructor(props, context) {
super(props)
...
}
```

and make shure you added drizzle to your context-types:

```
ExampleComponent.contextTypes = {
  drizzle: PropTypes.object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the drizzle object available, you just find it at drizzle.web3

If you use drizzle context or drizzle-react. drizzle is just an object that you can access directly. Make sure drizzle is in sync and not undefined. For example

`if(drizzle !== undefinde) console.log(drizzle.web3)`

and there it is.